# replace by threshold in df in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a df such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
A 10 20
B 3 34
C 3 21
D 34 4
```

and I would like to replace all value in `COL2` and `COL3 < 10` by "S"
and all value `>=10` by "N.S"
and get

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
A N.S N.S
B S N.S
C S N.S
D N.S S
```

I tried :

```
tab$pvalue_cov[tab$COL1<10 ] <- "S"
tab$pvalue_cov[tab$COL1>=10 ] <- "N.S"
tab$pvalue_gc[ tab$COL2<10 ] <- "S"
tab$pvalue_gc[ tab$COL2>=10 ] <- "N.S"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset the columns and use `ifelse()` to fill them accordingly:

```
tab[c("COL2_p", "COL3_p")] <- ifelse(tab[c("COL2", "COL3")] < 10, "S", "N.S")
tab
  COL1 COL2 COL3 COL2_p COL3_p
1    A   10   20    N.S    N.S
2    B    3   34      S    N.S
3    C    3   21      S    N.S
4    D   34    4    N.S      S
```

**Data**:

```
tab <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "COL1 COL2 COL3 
A 10 20
B 3 34
C 3 21
D 34 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it directly as well :

```
cols <- c('COL2', 'COL3')
tmp <- tab[cols]
tab[cols][tmp < 10] <- 'S'
tab[cols][tmp >= 10] <- 'N.S'
tab
#  COL1 COL2 COL3
#1    A  N.S  N.S
#2    B    S  N.S
#3    C    S  N.S
#4    D  N.S    S
```